# Can a docker container connect to a mysql db not in another docker container?

Tags: mysql, docker, etl, debezium

I'm new to docker and trying to implement debezium for ETL. The problem we are facing is that our db is present on a server that does not involve docker and we wish to connect to that db and capture CDC. My questions is can we connect to the db without changing it? Any guidance will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, why shouldn't that be possible? What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry for replying late. Here is where I'm stuck:
docker run -it --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 debezium/zookeeper:1.3
docker run -it --name kafka -p 9092:9092 --link zookeeper:zookeeper debezium/kafka:1.3
docker run -it --name mysql --network=host mysql mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -p
docker run -it --rm --name mysqlterm --link mysql mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"'
Error response from daemon: conflicting options: host type networking can't be used with links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, so long as your Docker container on which Kafka Connect is running has a network route to your MySQL server you will be fine.

Here's an example of [Debezium with MySQL](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/kafka-connect-zero-to-hero/demo_zero-to-hero-with-kafka-connect.adoc); in this instance it connects to MySQL on Docker, but you would just change the `"database.hostname": "mysql",` to point to the actual IP or hostname of your MySQL server.